# Multipy numpy 3 dim array by 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra

I have two matrices, `m0.shape = [10, 3, 3]` and `m1.shape = [10, 3]`. What I want to do would done this way using loops:

```
m0 = np.zeros((10, 3, 3))
m1 = np.zeros((10, 3))
a = np.zeros((10, 3))
for i in range(10):
    a += m1 @ m0[i]
```

The question is: Can I somehow achieve the same result by using builtin numpy operations?

Comment: just m1 @ m0 is ok

Comment: `m1 @ m0` gives `shape = [10, 10, 3]`

Comment: then sum it (axis=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two options:

```py
import numpy as np

np.sum(m1 @ m0, axis=0)
```

or using [numpy.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)

```py
np.einsum('ij,kjl->il', m1, m0)
```

Comment: Are those the same?  What if `m1` was (8,3) shape?

Comment: @hpaulj I think the equality should hold, giving output of shape (8,3). What am I missing?

Comment: I was thinking of the `dot` way of broadcasting the dimensions.

Comment: The sum could be applied to `m0` before multiplication: `m1@(m0.sum(axis=0))`