# Multiply each vector of matrix by each matrix of 3d tensor

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two tensors `m1.shape = [a, b, b]` and `m2.shape = [a, b]`. What I want to do would done this way using loops:

```
ret = np.zeros_like(m2)
for idx, (m1_sub, m2_sub) in enumerate(zip(m1, m2)):
    ret[idx] += m2_sub @ m1_sub
```

In other words, multiply vector `m2[i]` by `m1[i]` and store results in matrix of size `[a, b]`. Is there any easy way to achieve this by using numpy builtins and avoiding loops?

Comment: How's this different from your previous question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67416208/multipy-numpy-3-dim-array-by-2d-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `m1` and `m2` with the respective shapes `(a,b,b)` and `(a,b)` you are doing this

```
a = 10
b = 5

m1 = np.random.randn(a,b,b)
m2 = np.random.randn(a,b)

ret = np.zeros_like(m2)

for i in range(a):
    ret[i] += (m2[i,:] * m1[i,:,:].T).sum(axis=1)
```

This is the same as

```
(m2[...,None] * m1).sum(1)
```

And this can be expressed equivalently using [`einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy-einsum)

```
np.einsum("ij,ijk->ik", m2, m1)
```

The first axis (the `i` subscript) in `m2` is being multiplied with the first axis in `m1`.

The second axis is being reduced according to `sum(axis=1)`, this is because we omit the `j` subscript in the output of the einsum equation.

There is no third axis in `m2` so it is being broadcasted against the third axis in `m1` (the `k` subscript).

Comment: That did the trick, thank you a lot for your explanation.